# Git: intermittent failure with remotes "Recv failure: Connection was reset"

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-credential-manager

After installing Git on the new Windows machine and pulling/pushing to the Azure DevOps remotes (which works fine on other machines) I intermittently get the following error:

`Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/...': Recv failure: Connection was reset`

And rarely:

`Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/...': Send failure: Connection was reset`

This happens sporadically - sometimes I get this error many times in a row, and at other times remote sync works OK...

Tried to reinstall Git with and without credential manager and other tweaks to global and repo configs - but nothing seems to resolve this permanently.

Comment: Perhaps you have a real time virus scanner running and is locking a file at the wrong time? You can create exception rules to not scan your repo folders. You might have to provide the info to a system administrator of your network.

Comment: @DrDoomPDX Thanks, will try shortly and report back.

Comment: @DrDoomPDX tried to add exceptions for repo folder to Windows Defender, also for git process in firewall, etc. Unfortunately, still the same intermittent "Recv failure..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, resolved it by disabling IPv6... It was causing issues related to OpenSSL SSL_connect failure.

More important, getting the Git verbose logs has ultimately helped to understand the issue:

`GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE_CURL=1 GCM_TRACE=1 git pull`

Comment: Can you detail the steps you took to solve your issue? Did you disable ipv6 at a remote repo level, a computer level, or somewhere in between?

Comment: @KurtHamilton computer level

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1545297/434340

Comment: The only workaround I've found so far is enforcing ipv4 at the command line level - e.g. `git pull -4`. I like to use GUIs, so was hoping for something more specific than disabling ipv6 at the system level. Thanks anyway.